# jQuery toggle goes into loop after 'N' clicks

Tags: jquery

I have a nested ul in my navigation when I click on the parent link it displays the child links, the problem is, if I click on the 1st nested link, then click again to close it works OK.

If I then go to the 2nd Nested link and do same works OK.

But if I then go back to the 1st nested link, it opens closes and then opens again and I cannot work out why.

It seems to keep a count of how many times I have clicked on the links and I cannot work out how to stop it.

Hopefully, someone with more experience with jQuery can help with this.

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".child-class-ul").hide();
    $("#navHdr li:has(ul.child-class-ul)").hover(function () {
        $(this).children("a").click(function () {
            $(this).closest("li").find("[class^='child-class-ul']").slideToggle();
            return false;
        });

    });

})
```

--------------------------- HTML---------------------------

```
<ul id="navHdr" class="nav navbar-nav header-nav">
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a id="primary-header-link" href="/"><img src="/media/1002/mobile.png" height="80" width="180" /></a></li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" href="/about/">About</a> </li> 
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" href="/contact/">Contact</a> </li> 
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" href="/services/">Services</a> 
       <ul class="child-class-ul"> 
        <li class="child-nav nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" href="/services/">Services</a> </li> 
        <li class="child-nav nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" href="/services/accessories/">Accessories</a> </li> 
        <li class="child-nav nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" href="/services/buy-back/">Buy Back</a> </li> 
        <li class="child-nav nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" href="/services/warranty/">Warranty</a> </li> 
        <li class="child-nav nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" href="/services/repairs/">Repairs</a> </li> 
    </ul> </li> 
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" href="/">Login/Create</a> 
    <ul class="child-class-ul">
        <li class="child-nav nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" href="/members-dashboard/create-account/">Create Account</a> </li> 
        <li class="child-nav nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" href="/members-dashboard/login/">Login</a> </li> 
    </ul> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

---------------------Fix-------------------

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".child-class-ul").hide();

    $(".nav-item > p").click(function() {
        $(this).next(".child-class-ul").toggle("slow");
    });
})
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. It also sounds like there may be an event propagation issue at play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding new click events every time the user hovers over the `li`; the more times the user hovers, the more click events will fire from a single click.

It doesn't look like you need the hover event at all, since all you're really using it for for is limiting the `a` selector.  You can also simplify those selectors quite a bit (the `:has()` is unnecessary, since the event will have no effect if applied to an element it doesn't match; and you don't need `[class^='...']` when you know the exact class name.)

**Update** 
Now that you've provided your HTML, a second problem reveals itself: you're using the links to trigger the opening and closing of the submenus, but you're *also* using the same links as, you know, links. To other pages.    This can't work, because the script that enables the opening/closing of the submenus needs to prevent the links from working as links, and taking the user to another page before the submenu can open.

I've modified the script below to *only* return false if a submenu is present; this way the remaining links will behave normally.

This does mean that the URLs on the list items with submenus -- `/services` in "Services" and `/` in "Login/Create" -- remain unreachable; you'll need to decide whether those links should exist as page links or as affordances for the submenus, they can't be both.

(Just as a user interface note, you should visually distinguish between the links that point to new pages vs those that open submenus, so users don't get caught by surprise.)

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".child-class-ul").hide();
  $("#navHdr li a").click(function() {
    var submenu = $(this).closest("li").find(".child-class-ul");
    if (submenu.length) {
      submenu.slideToggle();
      return false;
    } else {
      // no submenu exists, so do nothing. This allows the event to bubble normally and fire the link href
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="navHdr" class="nav navbar-nav header-nav">
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" href="/about/">About</a> </li> 
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" href="/contact/">Contact</a> </li> 
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" href="/services/">Services</a> 
       <ul class="child-class-ul"> 
        <li class="child-nav nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" href="/services/">Services</a> </li> 
        <li class="child-nav nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" href="/services/accessories/">Accessories</a> </li> 
        <li class="child-nav nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" href="/services/buy-back/">Buy Back</a> </li> 
        <li class="child-nav nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" href="/services/warranty/">Warranty</a> </li> 
        <li class="child-nav nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" href="/services/repairs/">Repairs</a> </li> 
    </ul>
  </li> 
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" href="/">Login/Create</a> 
    <ul class="child-class-ul">
        <li class="child-nav nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" href="/members-dashboard/create-account/">Create Account</a> </li> 
        <li class="child-nav nav-item" role="presentation"> <a class="nav-link" href="/members-dashboard/login/">Login</a> </li> 
    </ul> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have added my HTML, as your code works on example, but still, mine does not allow clicking links

Comment: I updated the answer with your HTML (and I believe I have an explanation for the "mine does not allow clicking links" part.)

Comment: This outta do it. Nice write up @DanielBeck. Prime example of why examples should include a full working example since this was a combination of issues.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the reply, sorry for the delay in getting back as waiting for a response from the client. I could not show the HTML as was not allowed at 1st, I had a feeling that it could not be done, but that was clients spec. Anyway, I have been allowed to change code now and I'm using a p tag within li, makes it much easier to achieve what the client required. Have put modified code up in case anyone else needs help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that everytime you hover it adds a new event-handler to all the a-tags. So when you keep hovering and clicking it goes crazy

maybe you should try setting 1 event on #navHdr with "on".

```
$("#navHdr").on("click", "li:has(ul.child-class-ul) a", function(){
    $(this).closest("li").find("[class^='child-class-ul']").slideToggle();
});
```

Not sure if example works.
With the "on" event you can add a child-selector, so on each click it checks if the element matches your selector.

Answer (score 0):

Your binding a function to `$("#navHdr li:has(ul.child-class-ul)").hover` which then binds a function to `$(this).children("a").click`.

Basically every time you hover over that element, you are adding another click event handler that is going to fire.

Unless you **need** the hover function for something else, this should work.

```
$("#navHdr li:has(ul.child-class-ul) a")..click(function () {
        $(this).closest("li").find("[class^='child-class-ul']").slideToggle();
        return false;
});
```

Comment: I'm still struggling with how to fix this, any working example would be appreciated.

Comment: @GeorgePhillipson i added an update, but unless you can make a codepen or some link to an actual example, that's the best anyone is going to be able to do.

Comment: Hi Matti, no luck your example has the same problem I'm getting. I can get the nested link to drop down, but then none of the other links works.

Comment: @GeorgePhillipson it is likely a combo of the jquery and your markup. Without a working example, we won't really be able to help.